# Bind .m2 file to docker on build stage

Tags: maven, docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

I tried build a spring boot project in docker container based on below docker file.But every times all mvn dependency download from internet. 
How can I bind local .m2 file when i build the docker file.

This is my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine AS build 
COPY /src /usr/src/javaspring/src
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/javaspring
COPY Dockerfile /usr/src/javaspring
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/javaspring/pom.xml clean install


FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/src/javaspring/target/javaspring-1.0.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT [“java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Volumes and bind mounts apply when the container is running, not when building the docker image

Comment: @Sathya yes! but is it way to mount my local .m2 to the docker run inside the docker file

Answer (score 2):

You should mount the content of your project into the docker image and the `$HOME/.m2/` into the image instead of copying everything into the image and building a new image..

The `$PWD` is the local directory where your `pom.xml` file is located and the `src` directory exists...

```
docker run -it --rm \
  -v "$PWD":/usr/src/mymaven \ (1)
  -v "$HOME/.m2":/root/.m2 \ (2)
  -v "$PWD/target:/usr/src/mymaven/target" \ (3)
  -w /usr/src/mymaven \ (4)
  maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine \ (5)
  mvn clean package
```

1. defines the location of your working directory where `pom.xml` is located.
2. defines the location where you have located your local cache.
3. defines the target directory to map it into the image under the given path
4. defines the working directory.
5. defines the name of the image to be used.

So you don't need to create an new image to build your stuff with Maven. Simply run an existing image via the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm \
  -v "$PWD":/usr/src/mymaven \
  -v "$HOME/.m2":/root/.m2 \
  -v "$PWD/target:/usr/src/mymaven/target" \ 
  -w /usr/src/mymaven \
  maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine mvn clean package
```

Comment: thank you. but docker run command and my situation is deferent. I add new code. I think now you can understand the situation. When we use docker run command we can mount folders. but when we use run command in docker file it can’t do.

Comment: What do you mean by `I add new code` ..If course you change your own project ?...

Comment: sry I changed my docker file. when run:-  ( docker build . ) it download all the maven dependance every time. can i link my local m2 with docker build

Answer (score 2):

Since Docker Engine 18.09, there is a new set of build enhancements and one of them is "*Cache Mounts*". It will not let you mount your local `.m2` - it addresses the need for caching dependencies in a different way. To use it specify `--mount` option to your `RUN` command:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM maven:3.8.3-jdk-11 AS maven-builder
...
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=m2-cache,sharing=shared,target=/root/.m2  \
  mvn --file /xyz/pom.xml package
```

More: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md